# how to use android device administrator functions properly

Tags: android

i am working on android anti lost and i need some help with device administrator
it is implemented and activated
if i use this it locks the device

```
DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDevicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

and this changes the password

```
mDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(PASSWORD, 0);
```

1)What type of password it will set?
2)How to remove the password(anytype)?if i give null in place of password will it remove the password?
3)How to unlock the device?
i tried to find information about it but there are no examples or information about it.

Comment: `What type of password it will set?` what do you mean? do you mean whether it will be alphanumeric or numeric only?

Comment: @Sagar yes what is it by default?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)What type of password it will set?

It depends on the Device policy and the policy that you have enforced programatically.

You can set the policy as follows:

`policyManager.setPasswordQuality(componentName, qualityValue);`

Where `qualityValue` can be any of following:

```
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED,
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING,
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC,
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC,
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC,
DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_COMPLEX;
```

> 2)How to remove the password(anytype)?

`policyManager.resetPassword(newPassword, 0);`

> Calling with a null or empty password will clear any existing PIN,
>   pattern or password **if the current password constraints allow it**.

You need to be careful while using it. Check the returned value to confirm the changes have taken place.

> 3)How to unlock the device?

**Not possible**

Comment: Thanks i am going to test it

Comment: @Arslankhan no problem. Let me know outcome of your tests